# Where did Leia get the Bounty Hunter suit she wore in Jabba’s palace?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi, princess-leia

In the beginning of *Return of the Jedi*, Leia has acquired a fancy bounty-hunter suit.

> She uses it to disguise herself and help Luke break Han Solo out.
>
>  [image: Leia]

I'd guess bounty-hunter suits are not sold in shops in "the galaxy far far away", so my question is: **where did Leia get this suit?**

Both canon and Legends answers are acceptable.

Comment: There must be military surplus store all over the galaxy, no?

Comment: @Max Citation needed! Also, this could be another question on it own.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thOQwKCm-IY

Comment: I don't think there's a galaxy-wide standard for "bounty hunter uniforms."  Bounty hunters wear whatever they like and have access to.

Comment: I'm not entierly sure we need spoiler tags on a 30 year old film.

Comment: @Jeremy French, I only watched the original star wars trilogy in 2016. The spoiler tag is appropriate.

Comment: @BernardtheBear isn't the fact that Leia wears a bounty hunter costume the spoiler, though?

Comment: "I'd guess bounty-hunter suits are not sold in shops"--why not? Bounty hunters have to get them from somewhere. They're independent operators by definition, and there's no standard loadout among the hunters seen in ESB. Hunting bounties makes you a bounty hunter, not dressing a certain way.

Comment: I'm guessing they are sold in shops because I can't see Boba Fett sitting down at a sewing machine with a bolt of calico.

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think we ever see Star wars characters shopping for any clothes in the movies or TV spin-offs, do we? Wonder if Lando Calrissian and Darth Vader bumped into each other while shopping for capes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Maz Kanata helps her get it

In the Canon animated micro-series ["Star Wars Forces of Destiny"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Forces_of_Destiny), Leia is shown defeating [Boushh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boushh) and presumably stealing his armour

> Maz: Frozen in carbonite?
> Leia: Oh! Chewie said you can help us. We wouldn't ask if Han weren't in a tight spot.
> Leia: So what's the plan?
> Maz: Patience. The solution will present itself.
> Leia: Ugh! We've got a problem!
> Maz: No That's the solution!
> Leia: How?
> Maz: **You need a disguise. And a bounty hunter is perfect!**
> Leia: Oh, you've got to be kidding me!
> ...
> Maz: I'd say this armor is just your size.
> <sub>[Season 2 Episode 6 - Bounty Hunted](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_Hunted)</sub>

### Legends

While the tale in Legends is similar, Boushh getting into a struggle with the Black Sun crime syndicate and ending up dead, it wasn't Leia that directly stole his armour. In fact, it is [Xizor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xizor)'s Human Replica droid, [Guri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guri) which ends up killing him, for demanding extra payment.

Guri then provides Leia with the Armour for her to infiltrate Coruscant and meet Xizor. Organa kept the armour and once again used it to infiltrate Jabba's palace. <sup>[Citations coming]</sup>

Comment: ninj'd by a minute

Comment: I actually came here to answer it just after finishing watching it on youtube, was incredibly nervous about the grey banner appearing and saw a comment appear with the same youtube link. Hung my head in shame as I pressed enter.